# Searching for Chinese text throws UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7, python-twitter

I'm using [python-twiter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) to search for tweets using Twitter's API and I have a problem with chinese terms. Here is a minimal code sample to reproduce the problem:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import twitter

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key = "...", consumer_secret = "...",
                  access_token_key = "...", access_token_secret = "...")

api.VerifyCredentials()
print u"您说英语吗"
r = api.GetSearch(term=u"您说英语吗")
```

I get this error:

```
您说英语吗
Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "so.py", line 9, in <module>
    r = api.GetSearch(term=u"您说英语吗")
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_twitter-0.8.7-py2.7.egg/twitter.py", line 2419, in GetSearch
    json = self._FetchUrl(url, parameters=parameters)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_twitter-0.8.7-py2.7.egg/twitter.py", line 4041, in _FetchUrl
    url = req.to_url()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg/oauth2/__init__.py", line 440, in to_url
    urllib.urlencode(query, True), fragment)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1337, in urlencode
    l.append(k + '=' + quote_plus(str(elt)))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: have you tried encoding it? `u"您说英语吗".encode('utf8')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there is a bug in `GetSearch`: https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/issues/detail?id=210. I've tried to search for "Putin" in Russian ("Путин") and got the same error too. Playing with encoding didn't help.

As a workaround, you can use `twitter` package (https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from twitter import *

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(token="...", token_secret="...", consumer_key="...", consumer_secret="...")))

print t.search.tweets(q=u"您说英语吗")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is `OAuth` in your code, where do I get it from?

Comment: Yep, it works fine, thanks again, I didn't import OAuth from twitter module. BTW It is unfortunate that two different modules have the same name...

Answer (score 0):

Also, try adding the code below before using non-English text

> import sys
>
> reload(sys)
>
> sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")